# meteor & react split break down a Meteor app into packages targeting both mobile and desktop

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I want to split my meteor app into web and mobile/cordova parts, however I do not want to duplicate code nor create 2 separate projects. I also want to use React instead of Blaze, as I am more familiar with it (only recenlty started using meteor). There are a lot of discussion how to better split your code for web/mobile (just google), however I liked local packages approach and determined to make it work.

I have found this great [github repo](https://github.com/Compy/meteor-mobile-desktop) which shows how to split web and app code, however I am struggling to achieve similar results when adding react. So if someone has a repo or post about how to do it, please share. If no, may be we can make it easy for other developers by making a step by step guide here in this question.

I have not done anything with packages in meteor. So please be patient :-)

Currently I am struggling with even making one package working in my meteor app. So far I have the following (after creating and cleaning meteor app):

1) Run the following command

meteor create --package app-base

2) created root.html in project folder and populated it with

```
<head>
  <title>despite</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="render-target"></div>
</body>
```

3) added some code to app-base.jsx:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // Use Meteor.startup to render the component after the page is ready
    React.render(<App />, document.getElementById("render-target"));
  });
}
```

4) Added App.jsx:

```
App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello World!
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

5) added react and files to package.js:

```
...
api.use(['ecmascript', 'react']);
api.addFiles(['app-base.js', 'App.jsx']);
...
```

6) added app-base to .meteor/packages file

At this point builds, but when opening browser window I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

Seems like Meteor.startup is run before the DOM is rendered?

UPDATE:
I added `console.log(document.getElementById("render-target")` just before `ReactDOM.render` and it is `null` for some reason... 
I also tried

```
document.body.innerHtml = '<div id="render-target"></div>'
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('render-target'));
```

and then

```
const element = document.createElement('div');
documnet.body.appendChild(element)
ReactDOM.render(<App />, element);
```

And now it renders Hello World on the page! Sweet! Not sure about soundness of this approach though. Also after deleting html file in project dir, app still works

Comment: You still need something to render the template. Do you have code that is supposed to do this? A router?

Comment: @MasterAM Hey! i actually made the template work, currently struggling with jsx not transpiling automatically inside the package. However I have added react into package's client dependecies

Comment: @MasterAM updated the question to reflect current problem

Comment: You are trying to use `jsx` syntax in a '.js' file. (you cannot use plain `<app />` in JS).

Comment: @MasterAM That's embarassing :-( . Ye that was the reason I had error. changed app-base.js to app-base.jsx and the project is building just fine, however when opening browser window I have the following error: `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.` It seems that `div` is not rendered yet in Meteor .startup

Comment: @MasterAM I updated my question. React now is successfully rendered on the page. However I think my solution is a workaround and I do not understand why it did not work previously

Comment: I would not manually render the element in the package code. Using one of the available routers (`reaktor` or `react-router`) seems like a better alternative.

Comment: @MasterAM to use react-router I need to render inital component first, be it router or just a simple component. Or is there a way to add react-router with the way that you describe?